# Parse links if pagination exists, using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have modified my script and now it is running smooth and fine.

What I have done, thanks to SO support.

1. Open URL as www.my.url
2. Open all 20 links one by there and saving the Names

But, what I noticed, that www.my.url has 20 pages (pagination)
So, current way of script is working only for 1st pagination
My code is here

```
public class GetAllLinks {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Dell//chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.reklama.lv/ru/manufacture/build-works/uslugi/table.html");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //Get list of web-elements with tagName  - a
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//em[@class='view1']")).click();
        List<WebElement> demovar = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"big_icon_view\"]/ul/li/p/a"));
        System.out.println(demovar.size());

        ArrayList<String> hrefs = new ArrayList<String>(); //List for storing all href values for 'a' tag
        for (WebElement var : demovar) {
            System.out.println(var.getText()); // used to get text present between the anchor tags
            System.out.println(var.getAttribute("href"));
            hrefs.add(var.getAttribute("href"));
        }

        int i = 0;
        for (String href : hrefs) {
            driver.navigate().to(href);
            boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@id='NameTitle']")).size() > 0;
            if (isPresent) {
                String test = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"NameLink\"]")).getText();
                System.out.println(test);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No name found");
            }
            Thread.sleep(3000); // To check if the navigation is happening properly.
        }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before, it will parse all links which are visible on 1st page.
But, I also need to implement pagination.

So, I tried to adding a pagination here

```
for (WebElement var : demovar) {
            System.out.println(var.getText()); // used to get text present between the anchor tags
            System.out.println(var.getAttribute("href"));
            hrefs.add(var.getAttribute("href"));
        }
```

and was adding something like

```
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//paginationButton")).isDisplayed() {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//paginationButton")).click();
     System.out.println(var.getText()); // used to get text present between the anchor tags
                    System.out.println(var.getAttribute("href"));
                    hrefs.add(var.getAttribute("href"));
            } else {
System.outprintln("no more pagination button");
}
```

Assuming, that on second page, script will check other 20 links, and open them one by one.
But, unfortunatelly here I'm failing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use pagination, after going to page 2, you need to use the findElements method again. And refill hrefs.

Like this after last "for" loop ends:

```
    demovar = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"big_icon_view\"]/ul/li/p/a"));

    hrefs.clear();
    for (WebElement var : demovar) {
        hrefs.add(var.getAttribute("href"));
    }
```